# Selenium IDE: Click on a particular item by name (not the XPath)

Tags: selenium

I've recorded a Test Case in Selenium IDE where I access to a newspaper and click on a certain element (a link to a blog by KEITH DUGGAN). The commands recorded are these:

open | http://www.irishtimes.com/

clickAndWait | link=Sport

clickAndWait | //div[@id='content']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span

http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/8971/seleniumtest.jpg

The problem I see with this, is that if the order of the blogs displayed are changed, my Test Case won't work anymore, because instead of accessing to KEITH DUGGAN's blog it will access to a different one.

Is there a way I can tell Selenium that I want to access to KEITH DUGGAN's blog and not the third blog in a list? Basically, I want to access to an item by its text linked and not the possition (XPath)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
xpath=//span[text()='Keith Duggan: Sideline Cut']
```

or

```
css=span:contains('Keith Duggan: Sideline Cut')
```

That will always find that blog

Comment: Hi AutomatedTester!

Both options worked perfectly fine. How did you know about the "text()" and the "contains" options? I couldn't find them in the Selenium tutorial. 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are also many ways to construct an xpath, for example you could do

```
//span[@name='MySpanName']
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on selenese [documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#locators) for possible selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use Firebug to construct CSS identifiers. These should be position independent.